# Can't remove string from list of lists in Python

Tags: python

Struggling big time with this. The user makes a guess and i'm trying to match to the list of lists with a HIT or a MISS.  I also am trying to remove the string from the list if there is a HIT.

```
player_ships = [['a1','b1','c1'],['a2','a3']]
print(player_ships)
guess = input("guess")
while any(guess in ship for ship in player_ships):
    print("HIT")
    for ship in player_ships:
        ship.remove(guess)
else:
    print("Miss!")
```

If i enter a valid value from the list for a guess --example: a1--i'm getting a traceback error to the ship.remove(guess) line with a "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list error"  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Python `list` is a [Mutable Sequence Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#mutable-sequence-types), and its `remove` method is documented there. See footnote 3, which states: *"remove raises ValueError when x is not found in s."*

You want to remove the guess from the ship-list that contains the guess. You can either **ask permission** by first checking for containment (not recommended):

```
for ship in player_ships:
    if guess in ship:
        ship.remove(guess)
```

Or, you can **beg forgiveness** by catching the exception. Unlike many other languages, Python's exceptions are considered *cheap,* and therefore you are encouraged to rely on trying something, catching the exception, and moving on:

```
for ship in player_ships:
    try:
        ship.remove(guess)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: well Mr. Hastings, once again you've come to my rescue.  i need to get my head around more about why this is actually working but thank you for your help here.

Comment: I think the important part is that there are several lists, one per ship. When you do a remove on a list that *doesn't* contain a match, it raises. You need to either avoid that, or eat the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can't `remove` an element from a list if it's not there. Otherwise Python will throw an exception, as you see.

Say `guess = "a1"`.

Your code iterates over `player_ships`.

The first element of which is `['a1','b1','c1']`. You can remove `a1` from this without an error because it's there.

But the second element in the loop is `['a2','a3']`. This does not contain `a1` and so you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because in the case of "HIT", you are trying to remove `guess` from the all the sub-lists of `player_ships`. But it is present in only one of the sub-list.

You should make a `if` check to verify `guess` is within the `ship` before you remove it.

Easier way to achieve this is to flatten `player_ships`. Even better to store it as a `set`. For example:

```
>>> player_ships = [['a1','b1','c1'],['a2','a3']]
>>> flatten_set = set(ship for ships in player_ships for ship in ships)
>>> flatten_set
set(['a1', 'c1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1'])
```

Then, rest of your code logic could be written as:

```
guess = input("guess")

while guess in flatten_set:
    print("HIT")
    flatten_set.remove(guess)
else:
    print("Miss!")
```